# How to have html tags in a string bean passed as the model of a g:render tag

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a template that I need to pass dynamic text to as a string. Some of the strings have html tags. When I use html tags I get errors. Any idea how to get around this?

```
 <g:render template="/modals/note" model="['copy':'<b>Note:</b> bla bla price is ${bean.dueAmount}']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL (Java Standard Tag Library) to first set the value.  Something like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:set var="note">
  <%-- Escape markup using c:out --%>
  <c:out escapeXml="false">
    <b>Note:</b> bla bla price is ${bean.dueAmount}
  </c:out>
</c:set>
```

Then use it:

```
<g:render template="/modals/note" model="['copy':${note}]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian but using model="['copy':${note}] causes an error.

Comment: Ok got it to work by removing the ${}. model="['copy':note]" but the only problem is it's treating the <b>Note:</b> as a string so when it renders it looks like this "<b>Note:</b> bla bla price is 1.00"

Comment: @ericb  I updated my answer to escape the xml - I thought maybe the template was doing that.  Granted - my solution is verbose using the JSTL tags - there must be a grails native equivalent but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working locally:

Parent gsp

```
<g:set var="note">
    <b>Note:</b> bla bla price is ${bean.dueAmount}
</g:set>

<g:render template="/modals/note" model="[copy: note]" />
```

Template gsp

```
<div id="note-module" class="modal fade hide"> 
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>${copy}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was able to remove the raw/none encoding because the `note` is set within the `g:set` body.

Comment: In my _note.gsp I only have one variable called ${copy} so not sure what you are referring to by your examples. I tried wrapping ${raw(copy)} in _note,gsp but this still gives the same error.

Comment: What does your _note.gsp look like?

Comment: <div id="note-module" class="modal fade hide">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>${copy}</p>
    </div></div>

Comment: I made a change based on your feedback.

Comment: Thanks tylerwal. The problem is I get an error when I try to pass any html tags even if I use a g:set variable. If I remove any html tags then all is good with your example. I still need to be able to pass html tags

Comment: Sorry tylerwal I miss spoke on my last comment. it's not an error I just get the <b> tag rendering in the _note.gsp as a string and not html. So it renders like this "<b>Note:</b> bla bla price is 1.00". How can I get it to render as html and not a string.

Comment: @ericb It was working on my local machine with the exact code I put in the answer so it is possible, what version of Grails are you using?

Comment: 2.3.4 V. It works for me also but the html tags show up as text and not html unfortunately.

Comment: I tried it with 2.4.5; have you eliminated everything in your code (within reason) that would be affecting and tried passing the simplest html from the main gsp to the template? Even without the bean; get this working.